# Query doesnt return duplicate records - Mysql

Tags: mysql

My following query doesn't return duplicate records(Model_Number), is there a reason.Should return all duplicate model_number, with the following query it returns all unique.The Mysql has 2,17,092 records in total

```
SELECT AZ_Code, Model_Number
FROM dumpdata
GROUP BY Model_Number
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

Comment: Since you are grouping it does returned the duplicates but grouped(those unique model_number are in fact the ones which are duplicates).If you want too see the duplicates as they are JOIN on this subquery

Comment: @Mihai I do not understand what do you mean by "As they are JOIN on this subquery "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers should work, but I would expect this one to be much faster (as MySQL usually JOINs to subqueries more effectively than it uses them elsewhere, such as in WHERE clauses).

```
SELECT dd.AZ_Code, dd.Model_Number
FROM dumpdata AS dd
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT   Model_Number
   FROM     dumpdata
   GROUP BY Model_Number
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS repeatedModels 
ON dd.Model_Number = repeatedModels.Model_Number
```

Comment: I get an error when I run the query #1052 - Column 'Model_Number' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Have you indexed Model_Number? and what is the field's data type?

Comment: let me reboot the server and try it again

Comment: Model_Number - varchar(255)

Comment: When dealing with larger numbers of rows, indexing can help with grouping, ordering, conditions in WHERE clauses and used for JOINs; and when dealing with character data the benefits can be even more pronounced; comparing 2 million unindexed integers is a lot faster than comparing 2 million strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause means you want just one result per unique value you group by (and the fact you can query fields not in it is a MySQL oddity). You could work around with with the use of the `in` operator:

```
SELECT AZ_Code, Model_Number
FROM   dumpdata
WHERE  Model_Number IN (SELECT   Model_Number
                        FROM     dumpdata
                        GROUP BY Model_Number
                        HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: This query freezes phpmyadmin is there another way to run the query and export to csv

Answer (score 0):

One way of seeing the duplicates

```
SELECT d.AZ_Code, d.Model_Number
FROM dumpdata d
WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dumpdata  WHERE d.Model_Number=dumpdata.Model_Number)>1
```

Comment: This query freezes phpmyadmin, is there another way to run the query

Comment: @user580950 How many rows do you have?Also you have to be careful,cancelling a query in phpmyadmin doesnt means the query will also be cancelled on the server.

Comment: 2,17,092 records in total, I rebooted the server so that phpmyadmin works